# Unsure how to convert method definition to ES6

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, ecmascript-6

I'm currently in the process of converting our Backbone application to ES6 syntax like e.g. this:

```
action: function(e){},
```

Becomes

```
action(e) {}
```

However, now I'm having this code:

```
throttleEvent: _.throttle(function(e) {
    //do stuff
    }, 500);
}
```

And I can't seem to find how to convert this to valid syntax.
I tried

```
throttleEvent _.throttle((e) => {
    //do stuff
    }, 500);
}
```

And

```
throttleEvent() {
    return _.throttle((e) => {
    //do stuff
    }, 500);
}
```

But these all failed to work.

Help converting this to the valid syntax would be appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure.... But try second attempt without `return` keyword

Comment: @Kenny, that didn't work, it is able to access the throttleEvent method, but never reaches inside the _.throttle method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I'm not quite sure if the short syntax is applicable for your example.

Lets have a look at your start

```
action: function(e){},
```

you have an object, that object has a property called "action" and that property holds a function that later then can be called by obj.action().

Now to your example

```
throttleEvent: _.throttle(function(e) {}
```

Again you have an object, that has a property called throttleEvent. But the main difference is the value. The value is the **return Value** of the function _.throttle().

Taking from the documentation (https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#throttle)

> Creates a throttled function that only invokes func at most once per every wait milliseconds

So your property actually holds the function that you got returned from the library. That explains why your second approach does not work. Because in this version **every time** you call the object property, you **create a new** throttle function. 
(And to your first solution I think this is invalid syntax)

I think the best approach if you really want to use the short syntax is, assigning the throttle function to a variable before and then use it

For example something like this

```
const throttleFunction = _.throttle((event) => {
    //do stuff
}, 500);
const obj = {
    throttleEvent(event): any {
        return throttleFunction(event);
    },
};
```

But then it is to decide whether the ES6 syntax makes sense in this case or if you just stick with your original version

```
throttleEvent: _.throttle(function(e) {
    //do stuff
    }, 500)
```

Just because there is a different syntax available, does not mean you always have to use the new one. In some cases the "old one" makes actually more sense

Comment: thanks for the clear explanation and not only explaining the how but also the why. I think I'll stick with assigning the function to a variable, because with the original version I'm getting a syntax error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: you're welcome. there was a syntax error in the original version with the brackets. Probably was copy-paste related though. I updated my answer. In my code the syntax is valid. Maybe the syntax error is in a different place

Comment: One thing to keep in mind when wrapping a function with throttle is that the context is lost if not wrapped correctly. So `this` might not be what you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

try this syntax:

```
_.throttle(() => //Do stuff, 5000)
```